# Write a program that reads a file with numbers separated by commas and print those numbers to the turtle screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Question: Write a program that reads in sequences of numbers from a file and displays them in a grid on a graphics screen. For this program, you can assume that there are 4 lines each with no more than 4 entries per line. The entries on each line are separated by commas.

For example, consider a file which contains:

```
12,13,14,15
8,9,10,11
4,5,6,7
0,1,2,3
```

This is my program:

```
from turtle import*

def file():
  filename = input("Please enter a filename: ")
  openfile = open(filename, "r")
  readlines = openfile.readlines()

  for lines in readlines:
    nums = lines.strip().split(",")

  return nums

def turtle(n):
  row = 0
  wn = Screen()
  pen = Turtle()
  wn.setworldcoordinates(-0.5,3.5,4.5,-1.0)
  row = row + 1
  pen.up()
  for i in range(len(n)):
    pen.goto(i,row)
    pen.write(i, font=("arial", 30))
  row = row + 1


def main():
  y = file()
  w = turtle(y)


main()
```

This program is working, but it is printing only the last row numbers from the file. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from turtle import*

def file():
    filename = "t.txt"
    openfile = open(filename, "r")
    readlines = openfile.readlines()
    nums=[]
    for lines in readlines:
        nums.append(lines.strip().split(","))

    return nums

def turtle(n):
    print(n)
    row = 0
    col = 0
    wn = Screen()
    pen = Turtle()
    wn.setworldcoordinates(-0.5,3.5,4.5,-1.0)

    pen.up()
    for numberRow in n:
        for number in numberRow:
            pen.goto(col,row)
            pen.write(number, font=("arial", 30))
            col+=1
        row += 1
        col = 0

def main():
    y = file()
    w = turtle(y)


main()
r = input()
```

Comment: ERROR: `"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nums' referenced before assignment"`

Comment: @malcom Ah my bad. Before your for loop add `nums = []`. You get that error because its trying to add your first line to a variable that doesn't exist. By using `nums = []` I am making sure `nums` exists before I add to it.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the turtle(n) function

Comment: @Malcolm Be patient, im looking at it.

Comment: @Malcolm Well all the numbers print for me. Do they need to be printed in a 4x4 grid like the txt file?

Comment: @Malcolm In that case there are a whole bunch of logical problems with your code. I posted working code, see if you can see the difference between yours and mine and why mine works.

Comment: ERROR: `"for number in i: NameError: name 'i' is not defined"`

Comment: it should be `for number in  numberRow:`

Comment: It is working now but printing everything in a single line. I want 4*4

Comment: @Malcolm The indentation was off when I pasted it. Try again. Try to understand why this code works, no point just handing this in as homework without understanding it or else itll bite you in the butt later.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version of the code. Notice the mainloop() call
from turtle import*, also uncomment out the first with statement and get rid of the second with statement is you want to take user input. Your code, doesn't close the file properly.  That is never good form.  Using the with statement ensures that the file you opened is closed at the end.  Python is good at reclaiming memory, but you should never leave it to chance and it is good form to make sure you get your memory back.

```
def file():
  #with open(input("Please enter a filename: "), 'r') as data: 
  with open('test.txt', 'r') as data:
    nums = []
    for lines in data.readlines():
      nums.append(lines.strip().split(","))
  return nums

def turtle(n):
  wn = Screen()
  pen = Turtle()
  wn.setworldcoordinates(-0.5,3.5,4.5,-1.0)
  row = 0
  col = 0
  pen.up()
  for ele in n:
    for i in ele:
      pen.goto(row, col)
      pen.write(i, font=("arial", 30))
      row += 1
    row = 0
    col += 1
  mainloop() 


def main():
  y = file()
  w = turtle(y)

main()
```